# Largest set of 4 digit codes that do not share 3 digits

Tags: combinatorics

[This question is [based on one from Reddit]](https://www.reddit.com/r/theydidthemath/comments/98vosu/request_with_a_4_digit_code_how_many_unique_codes/)

Consider the set A of 4-digit numbers 0000-9999. We want to construct a set B from the set A such that every item in B differs from every other item in B by at least 2 digits. For example, if 1234 is in B, then 0234, 9234, 1264, etc cannot be in B, but 5634 can be in B.

Specifically:

1. What is the size of the largest set B?
2. How do we go about generating B from A?

I've hit a dead end trying to find a closed-form solution. A simulation got me up to 950 for the largest size for set B, so I know the largest size is at least 950. Intuition tells me the max is 1000, but I have no idea how to prove that or how to generate a/the set of 1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum is indeed $1000$. Let $B$ be the set of numbers whose digit sum is a multiple of $10$. Some examples are $0000,0019,00028,3241$ and $7896$.

There are exactly $1000$ numbers in $B$, because for any three digits $a,b,c$, there is exactly one number in $B$ whose first three digits are $abc$. Furthermore, no two numbers in $B$ can agree in exactly three places, because any three digits of a number in $B$ uniquely determine the fourth digit.