# Creating sets of $4$ elements such that no two sets share $3$ elements

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory, extremal-combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

> The city of Mathlandia has $10$ politicians. Let $S$ denote the set containing all $\dbinom{10}{4}$ possible groups of $4$ of politicians.
>
> Denote a subset, $M$, of $S$, as *special* if no two elements of $4$ politicians in $M$ share $3$ politicians. For example, if we label the politicians, $1, 2, 3, \cdots, 10$, then the subset: $\{ (1, 2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5, 6) \}$ is special but the subset $\{(1, 3, 4, 10),  (1, 3, 6, 9), (2, 3, 4, 10) \}$ is not because elements $1$ and $3$ share $3, 4, 10$.
>
> What is the maximal size of a special subset?

### My Understanding

This problem is similar to this: [Largest set of 4 digit codes that do not share 3 digits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2897534/largest-set-of-4-digit-codes-that-do-not-share-3-digits)

However, what makes it different is that the digit $0$ is not allowed, order does not matter, and we cannot put the same number twice in a set of $4$ politicians (we need $4$ distinct politicians).

Due to these distinctions, I was unable to use Mike Earnest's solution to the linked problem. Does anyone know how to solve it?

How could we generalize for $n$ politicians? Is there some clean combinatorial method?

### My Current Idea for Solution: Why Is this Wrong?

There are $\dbinom{10}{3} = 120$ sets of $3$ politicians.

Each set of $4$ politicians in $M$ contains $4$ different of $3$ politicians. So, the total number of sets of $4$ must be $\frac{120}{4} = 30$.

I checked this via a Java code and saw that the answer of $30$ is incorrect: it should actually be $18$.

Furthermore, if we try another number instead of $10$, for example $6$, this solution gives $5$ sets of $4$. However, the maximal amount of sets is $3$ : $$(1234), (1256), (3456)$$

For $n = 5$, we don't even get an integer. We get $2.5$. What incorrect assuption is this solution making?

Comment: I am pretty sure that you cannot prove with code that $18$ is the maximum possible value. You can use code to find a set of size $18$, but you would need to search all possible subsets of size $19$ to prove that none work, and there are too many of them.

Comment: Did you mean to write $\frac{120}{4}=30$?  This would show that you can't have more than $30$ sets, but not that $30$ is achievable.

Comment: Yeah I meant $30$. Ok, what if we decreased it from $10$ politicians to say, $7$ or $8$. In that case, I know for sure that the answer would be $7$ and $14$. There has to be some sort of combinatorial way of coming up with this answer right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You observed that the four subsets of size $3$ derived from each subset of size four must be distinct from one another. This means that if $30$ sets were attainable, they would have to consist of all $4\cdot 30=120$ subsets of size $3$ exactly once. Therefore, you would need what is called a *Steiner quadruple system* (SQS) of order $10$. Fortunately, Steiner quadruple systems of order $n$ exist precisely when $n\equiv 2$ or $4\pmod 6$, so you can achieve $30$ sets.

It seems that constructing SQS's is a complicated matter, based on the abstract of this paper: [A new existence proof for Steiner quadruple systems](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10623-012-9621-6). However, in your case,  you can find the $30$ sets of size four in the La Jolla covering repository: [Covering design C(10, 4, 3)](https://ljcr.dmgordon.org/cover/show_cover.php?v=10&k=4&t=3). A covering design is more general then a Steiner system, but in this case they are the same.

---

What you are looking for is also known as a constant weight binary code with length $10$, weight $4$, and distance $4$. To translate this to the language of coding theory, you view subsets of $\{1,\dots,10\}$ of size $4$ as binary strings of length $10$ with $4$ ones. The condition that no two subsets share $3$ elements is equivalent to saying any two strings differ in at least four places, hence the distance of $4$.

In general, the number of strings in a code of length $n$, weight $w$, and distance $d=2e$ is at most
$$
\left\lfloor \frac{n}{w}\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{w-1}\cdots \left\lfloor \frac{n-w+e}{e}\right\rfloor\cdots\right\rfloor\right\rfloor
$$
This is the Johnson bound. For length $n$, size $4$ and weight $4$, this bound is certainly achievable when $n\equiv 2,4$ by a Steiner system of order $n$. There are lots of ad hoc ways to construct codes like this, you can find more codes and known upper bounds on [Andries Brouwer's website](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/codes/Andw.html).

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. That's pretty cool.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  For each 4-subset $A\in S$, let binary decision variable $x_A$ indicate whether $A\in M$.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_A x_A$ subject to "conflict" constraints
$$x_A + x_B \le 1 \text{ for all $A,B$ such that $|A \cap B| \ge 3$} \tag1$$
Constraint $(1)$ prevents selecting both $A$ and $B$.

A stronger formulation is to replace $(1)$ with "clique" constraints
$$\sum_{A \supset B} x_A \le 1 \text{ for all $B$ such that $|B| = 3$} \tag2$$
Constraint $(2)$ prevents selecting more than one subset that contains the same 3-subset.

In either case, the maximum turns out to be 30, as found by @MikeEarnest.